# Всплывающее меню при определенных условиях

Tags: javascript

Такая задача.

Оригинальная задача:

> Some page exists, where you can show or hide the menu. Menu visibility is controlled by JS script. Need to test this functionality, for this purpose you need to write the script.
>
> 3 types of users exist: non-authorized and shouldn’t see the menu, authorized and shouldn’t see the menu (with id =7), all other authorized users can see the menu.
>
> Need to write the JS script which should return False, when user is not authorized and False if user has id=7 and True for all other authorized users.
> You can use following API:
>
> - p.currentUser.isGuest() - this API returns True if the user is not authorized.
> - p.currentUser.getValue('id') - this API returns ID of current authorized user.
>
> Example: only non-authorized users have access:
>
> As advantage will be to write it in one row, without if/else.

Перевод:

> Существует некая страница, где ты можешь раскрывать или скрывать меню. Видимость меню контролируется JS скриптом. Нужно протестировать функциональность, для этого тебе потребуется написать скрипт
>
> Есть три типа существующих пользователей: не авторизированные - те кто не должны видеть меню, авторизированные которые не должны видеть меню (с id равному 7) и все остальные авторизированные пользователя которые могут видеть меню.
>
> Нужно написать JS скрипт который должен вернуть `false`, когда пользователь не авторизирован и `false`, если пользователь имеет id 7 и `true` для все остальных авторизированных пользователей. Вы можете использовать текущий API:
>
> - p.currentUser.isGuest() - этот API вернёт `true` если пользователь не авторизирован.
> - p.currentUser.getValue('id') - этот API вернёт ID текущего авторизированного пользователя.
>
> Пример: только не авторизированные пользователя имеет доступ:
>
> Как премущество писать его в одну строку без if/else. (P.S. от @NNL993, сам не понял к чему тут это.)

Ну я написал тернарку:

```
let user = +prompt('current user id')
user == null || id == '7' ?false:true;
```

Не понимаю, что делать с API которое в условии?

Comment: Желательно ещё вопрос перевести на русский (не обязательно строго, если будут оба варианта — будет отлично :) )

Comment: Код не должен быть воспроизводимым, вам сказали, что есть некая функция `p.currentUser.isGuest()` , дающая нужные данные - берете и вызываете, не интересно, как она работает)

Comment: Это решение отрешенное от ТЗ, Вам ясно указали что Вы можете использовать, и prompt там нет, есть функции, методы, замените и ОК, подозреваю что это тестовое задание и даже этого может не хватить, по-моему вопрос еще и про тестирование (написание юнит тестов)